# CMAKE missing sysroot when cross compiling

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ld

I am having some troubles setting up cross compiling with CMAKE. The toolchain I am using is created in yocto which works perfectly outside of cmake.

I have followed a tutorial to setup the following toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(tools /opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

# set sysroot
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/sifu/test-yocto/qemuarmdfs)
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/sifu/test-yocto/qemuarm)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

And get the following error when running cmake

```
The C compiler
"/opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /home/sifu/Projects/mv/doublepump-single-pump-sw.ss016m21_swapp/cc/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec4012536451/fast"

/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/build.make
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/build

make[1]: Entering directory
`/home/sifu/Projects/mv/doublepump-single-pump-sw.ss016m21_swapp/cc/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
/home/sifu/Projects/mv/doublepump-single-pump-sw.ss016m21_swapp/cc/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
1

Building C object
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/testCCompiler.c.o


/opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -o
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
/home/sifu/Projects/mv/doublepump-single-pump-sw.ss016m21_swapp/cc/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec4012536451

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

/opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
-Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4012536451.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
-o cmTryCompileExec4012536451 -rdynamic

... (A lot of ld errors similar to the one below)

/opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.9.1/ld:
cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: Leaving directory
`/home/sifu/Projects/mv/doublepump-single-pump-sw.ss016m21_swapp/cc/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

If I manually run the gcc command described in the log above with **--sysroot=/home/sifu/test-yocto/qemuarmdfs** it works for me. Why isn't cmake using the sysroot flag when the path to sysroot is added in the toolchain file.

Comment: Looks like CMake fails to detect that compiler supports `--sysroot` option. Is line `The C compiler identification is GNU` output by CMake when configure? BTW, you show toolchain with errorneous space before "gnueabi-gcc" in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable definition. This space is absent in your original toolchain file, isn't it?

Comment: When configuring it detects the correct C compiler `The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1.`. The space in CMAKE_C_COMPILER was just a cut and paste issue, i have edited the original question.

Comment: I am unsure, but probably the CMake project you tried to build modifies `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` somehow, so `--sysroot` option disappears. Could you try to build simple "Hello world" program with your toolchain?

Comment: The toolchain works perfectly with hello world as long as I use `--sysroot=/home/sifu/test-yocto/qemuarmdfs`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant to test **CMake** toolchain file with simple CMake project (e.g., which builds "Hellow world" program via `add_executable`). For such project CMake should add `--sysroot` option automatically, and you can see it when build with `make V=1`.

Comment: But the problem is that i cannot even make a cmake configuration. It fails long before when cmake test my compiler with a simple c-file. So I cannot compile my project since there is no Makefiles.

Comment: Hello @Tsyvarev , I have a doubt here. In the toolchain file, cross-compiler is specified as `SET(tools /opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr)`. But I expected it to be something like `SET(tools /opt/poky/1.7.1/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr)`. Why are we referring to `x86_64-pokysdk-linux`? I just wanted to know the difference here.

Answer (score 10):

I just hit this myself. The problem is that CMake only passes CMAKE_SYSROOT to compilers which specify what their command-line flag for receiving a sysroot is, and during the first probing in CMakeDetermineCompilerId doesn't yet know what compiler it's calling. Once it detects that it's GNU, Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake will do

```
#!cmake
set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OPTIONS_SYSROOT "--sysroot=")
```

After this is set, CMake will start passing "--sysroot=${CMAKE_SYSROOT}"

This is why running multiple times; despite the fact that the "check for working C compiler" failed the first time through, CMake still detected that the failing compiler was a flavor of GNU and cached that. So on the second attempt, it loads GNU.cmake, *does* pass `--sysroot`, and things work (then it has the same failure, but for CXX). On the third try CXX works too, and things actually pass.

You can fix this in a couple of ways, but I'm not sure what's really best

- Skip linking, so that CMake doesn't actually need the sysroot to succeed, using [CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html#variable:CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE)

  if((NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID) OR (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID))
  set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
  endif()
- Force the compiler ID detection early, so it will already know to load GNU.cmake (seemingly has to go in the cache to work within try_compile, not sure why)

  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID GNU CACHE STRING "")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID GNU CACHE STRING "")
- Tell CMake about --sysroot, even before it knows it's GNU

  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS_SYSROOT "--sysroot=")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS_SYSROOT "--sysroot=")

I'm not sure which is the best workaround, and I think the whole thing is arguable a CMake bug since it did detect the compiler id fine (using -c, and thus not needing to link), it just didn't reload GNU.cmake based on the results of CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID before checking whether the compiler works.

Answer (score 7):

I have two solutions of this problem:

1. I use the following code in the toolchain file:

   ```
   # compiler
   set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /path/to/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++)
   # sysroot location
   set(MYSYSROOT /path/to/sysroots/cortexa7-vfp-neon-telechips-linux-gnueabi)
   # compiler/linker flags
   set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   # cmake built-in settings to use find_xxx() functions
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${MYSYSROOT}")
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
   ```
2. Second solution is to use CMakeForceCompiler package in the toolchain file. It looks differently but I have the same result:

   ```
   # compiler
   include(CMakeForceCompiler)
   cmake_force_c_compiler(/path/to/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc GNU)
   cmake_force_cxx_compiler(/path/to/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ GNU)
   # sysroot location
   set(MYSYSROOT /path/to/sysroots/cortexa7-vfp-neon-telechips-linux-gnueabi)
   # compiler/linker flags
   add_definitions("--sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}")
   set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${MYSYSROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   # cmake built-in settings to use find_xxx() functions
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${MYSYSROOT})
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
   ```

BTW, I can't use [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable, since it available since CMake v3.0 only.

Comment: Both solution 1 and CMAKE_SYSROOT work for me (NXP QorIQ SDK 2.0 PPC64). Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

Also I think you need

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem, there is still no sysroot added to the compiler test command. However if i run cmake three times in a row it manage to skip the test and I get I somewhat working make system.